# Make form redirect to textbox value?

Tags: html, redirect, textbox

Alright, so im making a "warranty checker" i have an application ive created in c# that uploads a webpage to my server when a package is marked as shipped, which includes a countdown timer letting the customer know when their consoles warranty has expired. It looks as if my code is proper, however it obviously is not as i cant for the life of me get it to work.

Here is the code im using:

```
    <input name="txtSearch" maxlength="12" size="25" type="text" class="field" id="txtSearch" />
<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div class="button style="display:inline-block">
<a type="submit" href='http://www.example.com/warranty/' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value; return false;">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help on the matter.

Comment: what is your requirement? be more specific please

Comment: Im sorry, what im trying to to exactly would be if the user enters the number 00486738295 for example, into the textbox, i want the page to redirect from: http://www.themodshop.co/warranty/ to: http://www.themodshop.co/warranty/00486738295 when the click the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
<div class="button style="display:inline-block">
<a  onclick='window.location.href="http://www.themodshop.co/warranty/" + document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;'>Submit</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="txtSearch" maxlength="12" size="25" type="text" class="field" id="txtSearch" />
<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div class="button style="display:inline-block">
<a type="submit" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pgredirect();">Submit</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pgredirect(){
        window.location.href = 'http://www.themodshop.co/warranty/' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    }
</script>
```